# Firebug: How to save rendered Source Code?

Tags: javascript

I'm using Firebug's Inspector to view source code. My code has been modified by JavaScript. I'd like to save the rendered code to a file, so that I can more easily compare it to the unmodified source. I'm having no luck with copy/paste. When I attempt to select the code, the contents of the inspector changes.  I'm running OSX.

How can I save the rendered source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm.. Would expanding the HTML element in FB and then hitting CMD+A, CMD+C not help? What about using JS to copy the inner HTML of the top-most parent?

Comment: In the end, I used JavaScript to write the document source into an alert. I  then copied it from the alert. Not elegant, but it works. I've had no luck getting FireBug to show me the html source after it's modified by JavaScript.